# viewDidLoad Reloading Infinitely

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm running into a very odd bug, and it wasn't happening this morning despite not changing any code. I even reverted to a build that I was working on last week that I know was working and the same thing started happening. So what's happening is my viewDidLoad method keeps getting rerun, seemingly whenever I add a subview to my self.view or try to access information about self.view's current subviews. This happens infinitely, until I get an (EXC_BAD_ACCESS code = 2) error and the program crashes.

I'm totally at a loss for how to even go about fixing this problem, so any help would be greatly appreciated. I'll post my code below:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
    screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
    startLat = 42.332985;
    startLong = -71.473913;
    endLat = 42.327756;
    endLong = -71.469589;
    float cameraPosLat = (startLat + endLat) / 2.0f;
    float cameraPosLong = (startLong + endLong) / 2.0f;

    NSLog(@"Test Text"); **//This is a test message that prints everytime viewDidLoad is called again**


    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:cameraPosLat
                                                        longitude:cameraPosLong
                                                             zoom:18];
    mapView = [[GMSMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)];
    mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeSatellite;
    mapView.delegate = self;
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
   [mapView setMinZoom:18 maxZoom:mapView.maxZoom];
   **//Program reaches here**
   [self.view addSubview:mapView];
   **//Program does not reach here, program jumps back to top of viewDidLoad**
   NSLog(@"Please Reach Here");
}
```

Based on EridB's suggestion I tried moving my code into the viewWillAppear method rather than viewDidLoad and when I do that the code crashes in the segue to the Google Maps page from the menu page.

```
-(IBAction)toCars:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"To Cars");
    classification = @"car";
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toMap" sender:sender]; **//Crashes here**
}
```

This gives the following stack trace:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010952dc65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000109181bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001093f2478 -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] + 360
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109451384 +[NSArray arrayWithObjects:count:] + 52
    4   UIKit                               0x0000000109bc583f _UIViewTopDownSubtreeTraversal + 127
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000109ca4588 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:modalSourceViewController:presentationController:animationController:interactionController:completion:] + 710
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000109ca57ae -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 3079
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000109be068e +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 65
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000109ca77ca __62-[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke + 333
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000109ca7625 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 229
    10  My App                      0x00000001071869fe -[DTMenuViewController toCars:] + 126
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000109f197b6 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 262
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000109f18459 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 532
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000109f1d076 ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke662 + 51
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000109f1cf72 _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 254
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000109f12fed _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 2796
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000109bb6686 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1041
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000109bb72b2 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 666
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000109b7d581 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 246
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000109b8ad1c _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 18265
    20  UIKit                               0x0000000109b655dc _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2066
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109461431 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001094572fd __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109456934 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109456366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    25  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010bd9fa3e GSEventRunModal + 161
    26  UIKit                               0x0000000109b68900 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    27  My App                       0x0000000107181f03 main + 99
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010afda145 start + 1
    29  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
 )
 libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I'm really lost, and hoping somebody knows that answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Well for starters you should call `[super viewDidLoad]` at the top of the method.

Comment: Try to move this code under `viewWillAppear` and see the results

Comment: @Dima  Adding [super viewDidLoad] didn't change anything.

Comment: @EridB adding the code under viewWillAppear made it crash on the segue that brings me to this viewController.

Comment: @shadowarcher put some breakpoints to debug it, and inspect if the value of the `mapView` is nil, or if you have any nil value that you are trying to add  on a possible array.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `[super viewDidLoad]` before accessing self.view should fix this issue.

Remember calling `self.view` in your viewDidLoad without `[super viewDidLoad]` will implicitly load the view. Thus your `viewDidLoad` is invoked multiple times.

Comment: I added [super viewDidLoad] and it's still doing the same thing. I'll edit my original posting to reflect this.

Comment: Please post the header of the VC

Answer (score 0):

It's always better that you add your subviews in `initWithNibName:bundle:`. Here's what you should do :

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)bundleOrNil
{
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:bundleOrNil]))
    {
        screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
        screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
        startLat = 41.332985;
        startLong = -73.473913;
        endLat = 41.327756;
        //......
}
```

The `initWithNibName:bundle:` method is called before the view is loaded from the nib, and is only called once in the lifespan of the view controller.

Comment: `viewDidUnload` has not been used/called since iOS 5. You don't need to "unset" views. As long as there is no retain cycle/memory leak, they will be cleaned up on their own when the view controller is deallocated.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I guess, you always learn something new out of these forums. I'll edit the answer right away.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem, I called one of my UIView's "loadView" which incidentally caused all the problems. I changed the name of the UIView to "activityView" and everything worked fine.